# Java - Regex to Split Tokens With Minimum Size and Delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

I know I know, there are many similar questions, and I can say I read all of them. But, I am not good in regex and I couldn't figure out the regular expression that I need.

I want to split a String in Java, and I have 4 constraints:

1. The delimiters are [.?!] (end of the sentence)
2. Decimal numbers shouldn't be tokenized
3. The delimiters shouldn't be removed.
4. The minimum size of each token should be 5

For example, for input:

`"Hello World! This answer worth $1.45 in U.S. dollar. Thank you."`

The output will be:

`[Hello World!, This answer worth $1.45 in U.S. dollar., Thank you.]`

Up to now I got the answer for three first constraints by this regex:

```
text.split("(?<=[.!?])(?<!\\d)(?!\\d)");
```

And I know I should use `{5,}` somewhere in my regex, but any combination that I tried doesn't work.

For cases like: `"I love U.S. How about you?"` it doesn't matter if it gives me one or two sentences, as far as it doesn't tokenize `S.` as a separate sentence.

Finally, introducing a good tutorial of regex is appreciated.

**UPDATE:** As [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513504/chris-bode)  mentioned in the comments, it is almost impossible to solve questions like this (to cover all the cases happen in natural languages) with regex. However, I found HamZa's answer the closet, and the most useful one.

**So, Be careful! The accepted answer will not cover all possible use cases!**

Comment: Are we sure that at the end of each sentence, there is a space?

Comment: And, what happens if the sentence is shorter than 5 chars, i.e., `Hey!`?

Comment: @Juto It can be. In this example there are spaces, but not in all cases

Comment: @Juto It should be concatenate to the other sentences (if exists)

Comment: This is looking dangerously close to natural language parsing, which is not an application for regular expressions. Remember, regular expressions can parse regular languages. Written english is not a regular language. Any solution you get with regular expressions is going to be rough.

Comment: It can be? What do you mean, as it could be a very different approach if there is always a space after `.?!`

Comment: @Juto, I mean we cannot rely on that. But if there is a space, it should concatenate to the next string like my example " Thank you."

Comment: [My early answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377437/split-a-text-into-sentences/16377765#16377765) seems to work for most of your cases except for the `U.S.` case it fails. You just need to wrap it in a lookahead `(?=(?<=[.?!])\\s+(?=[a-z]))`

Comment: @AfshinMoazami [Take a look](http://regex101.com/r/vJ1nK1). It should work. Of course `\s+` should be `\\s+`.

Comment: @HamZa, but it doesn't tokenize the "Hello World!", does it? (it's a nice editor btw)

Comment: @AfshinMoazami Yes it did, btw I made a typo in there. [Take a look](http://regex101.com/r/xU3aD7). I've added the "substitution" option to see where it gets splitted.

Comment: @My early answer, It I do it right: "(?=(?<=[.!?])(?<!\\d)(?!\\d)\\s+(?=[a-z]))", it has the same problem as HamZa solution has. "Hello World!" is not tokenized.

Comment: @HamZa, in that online editor, it's fine. But in java, it shows these tokens: [Hello World! This answer worth $1.45 in U.S.] ,[ dollar. Thank you. He lives in the U.K.] and [ but still talks in dollars]

It's strange!

Comment: @AfshinMoazami Are you using case insensitive flag ? Add `(?i)` to the beginning of your expression `(?i)(?=(?<=[.?!])(?<![a-z]\.[a-z]\.)\\s+(?=[a-z]))`

Comment: Now, it works. Add it as an answer please :)

Comment: @ChrisBode, I agree that is "looking dangerously close to NL parsing", but there are some close answers that you can see. Thanks for the warning btw :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing my answer from a [previously made regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377765).
The regex was basically `(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[a-z])` which means match any whitespace one or more times preceded with either `.`, `?` or `!` and followed by `[a-z]` (not forgetting the `i` modifier).

Now let's modify it to the needs of this question:

1. We'll first convert it to a JAVA regex: `(?<=[.?!])\\s+(?=[a-z])`
2. We'll add the `i` modifier to match case insensitive `(?i)(?<=[.?!])\\s+(?=[a-z])`
3. We'll put the expression in a positive lookahead to prevent the "eating" of the characters (delimiters in this case) : `(?=(?i)(?<=[.?!])\\s+(?=[a-z]))`
4. We'll add a negative lookbehind to check if there is no abbreviation in the format `LETTER DOT LETTER DOT` : `(?i)(?<=[.?!])(?<![a-z]\.[a-z]\.)\\s+(?=[a-z])`

So our final regex looks like : `(?i)(?<=[.?!])(?<![a-z]\.[a-z]\.)\\s+(?=[a-z])`.

**Some links:**

- [**Online tester**](http://www.regexplanet.com/), jump to [JAVA](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html)
- [**Explain tool**](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) (Not JAVA based)
- [**THE regex tutorial**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [**Java specific regex tutorial**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)
- [**SO regex chatroom**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25767/regex)
- Some advanced nice regex-fu on SO
- [How does this regex find triangular numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627681/how-does-this-regex-find-triangular-numbers)
- [How can we match a^n b^n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644266/how-can-we-match-an-bn-with-java-regex)
- [How does this Java regex detect palindromes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664881/how-does-this-java-regex-detect-palindromes)
- [How to determine if a number is a prime with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795065/how-to-determine-if-a-number-is-a-prime-with-regex)
- ["vertical" regex matching in an ASCII "image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039670/vertical-regex-matching-in-an-ascii-image)
- [Can the for loop be eliminated from this piece of PHP code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262551/can-the-for-loop-be-eliminated-from-this-piece-of-php-code/18262967#18262967) 
  ^-- See regex solution, although not sure if applicable in JAVA

Comment: This fails if the abbreviation is actually at the end of the sentence, e.g. `I live in the U.S.A. We speak English.` Additionally, it still splits on abbreviations of only one part, e.g. `Employees at Grammar Inc. make pedantic comments on the internet.` Both of these are essentially unresolvable with RegEx.

Comment: @ChrisBode Yup, I know.

Answer (score 2):

What about the next regular expression?

```
(?<=[.!?])(?!\w{1,5})(?<!\d)(?!\d)
```

e.g.

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("(?<=[.!?])(?!\\w{1,5})(?<!\\d)(?!\\d)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Hello World! This answer worth $1.45 in U.S. dollar. Thank you.";

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(
        REGEX_PATTERN.split(input)
    )); // prints "[Hello World!,  This answer worth $1.45 in U.S.,  dollar.,  Thank you.]"
}
```

Comment: Technically, this is the correct answer, but I prefer the Hamza's answer, which doesn't split the "U.S." and "dollar"
Thanks buddy