# Joining two arrays using a common key in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays, relational

I've managed to extract data from a database and assigned them into array called `$NameandAge`

```
(Peter:12, Kim:32, Paul:23)
```

On the other hand, I have also extracted another set of data from a different set of database and assigned them into array `$StateandName`

```
(New York:Peter, Washington:Kim, Tennessee:Paul)
```

What I what to achieve is to join these two sets of array into one using the Name as the key to create a table like this:

```
New York Peter 12,
Washington Kim 32,
Tennessee Paul 23,
```

I have something like below, however this takes a very long time for execution, giving me a timeout. I am looking for a better way to achieve this.

```
for(){       ///////////////loop array $StateandName
     for(){      ////////////loop array $NameandAge
          if($nameinfirstarr == $nameinsecondarr){
               echo .....;  ////////print out the State, Name and Age   
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: a working example would be great

Comment: **you can look at this answer**
[PHP ARRAY JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915944/join-multidimensional-array-like-sql/46951115#46951115)

Answer (score 0):

No need for two loops:

```
foreach ($StateaandName as $state => $name) {
    $newarr[$state][$name] = $NameandAge[$name];
}
```

assuming that there's a 1:1 match between records in the two arrays, this will do the trick. If your arrays have different names and don't match up 1:1;, then you'd need TWO of these loops, one to work from each array in turn.

Comment: I'm not familiar with key arrays. Right now, what I'm having is just a single array element.

Comment: Perhaps can you show me how to assign the data to key and value arrays in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Use **array_merge()**.  Is a **PHP** function than merges both arrays, overwriting values for same keys,  when keys have string values,  instead of numeric ones, as your case.