# How to simulate the SQL LEFT JOIN operation using PHP arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, left-join, array-merge

I have an application that connects to multiple server. where one server will have ID that are foreign key to a table that is located on a different server. The issue here is that MySQL does not support linked servers so I can't run a left query that will LEFT join 2 tables located on separate servers.

So I have to pull 2 separate queries from 2 different server using PHP and they LEFT JOINing them using PHP.

Please note that the array keys listed below needs to be dynamic. I can't use a fixed names are different queries will have different column name. The example below use the phone_call_id as they key to use to join both arrays and it combines the column name. if $right_array has more columns then these columns need to be added to the final array.

so I have 2 array

```
$left_array = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [start_on] => 2014-09-14 19:50:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-14 19:51:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 122
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [start_on] => 2014-09-15 05:53:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-15 06:53:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 123
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [start_on] => 2014-09-15 05:53:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-15 06:53:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 
        )
)
```

The right array will look like this

```
$right_array = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 1
            [phone_call_id] => 122
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [account_id] => 2
            [phone_call_id] => 123
        )
)
```

the results needs to be like this array

```
$joined_array = 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [start_on] => 2014-09-14 19:50:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-14 19:51:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 122
            [account_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [start_on] => 2014-09-15 05:53:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-15 06:53:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 123
            [account_id] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [start_on] => 2014-09-15 05:53:00
            [end_on] => 2014-09-15 06:53:00
            [subject] => This is a new event
            [client_id] => 
            [all_day_event] => 0
            [event_type] => Event
            [phone_call_id] => 
            [account_id] =>

        )
)
```

Comment: **you can look at this answer**
[PHP ARRAY JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915944/join-multidimensional-array-like-sql/46951115#46951115)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function simulates the left join operation

```
   //function to simulate the left join
    function left_join_array($left, $right, $left_join_on, $right_join_on = NULL){
        $final= array();

        if(empty($right_join_on))
            $right_join_on = $left_join_on;

        foreach($left AS $k => $v){
            $final[$k] = $v;
            foreach($right AS $kk => $vv){
                if($v[$left_join_on] == $vv[$right_join_on]){
                    foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                        $final[$k][$key] = $val; 
                } else {
                    foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                        $final[$k][$key] = NULL;            
                }
            }
        }
       return $final;
    }
```

//the function can be used like so assuming the column name in the left array is the same name as the right array

```
$final_array = left_join_array($left, $right, 'phone_call_id');
```

//the function can be used like so assuming the column name in the left array "are different but has the same corresponding value"

```
$final_array = left_join_array($left, $right, 'phone_call_id', 'p_c_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

hi You can try this piece of code this will give you a merged array similar to left outer join:

```
foreach($left_array as $k => $v){
   foreach($right_array as $kk => $vv){
     if($v['id'] == $vv['account_id']){
         foreach($vv as $key => $val){
             $left_array[$k]['right_'.$key] = $val; 
         }
     }
   }
}
```

you will get fields from right array with prefix 'right_'

Comment: Hi, I took your code a modified it a little to make it fit my need. but the issue that I am running into now is that when the phone_call_id is null then I will have a missing cell in the array. I will put the code that I currently have in my post so you can take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry I think I didn't get what you are trying to say. According to logic if some field is null or empty it will return same only, correct?   Please put your code. I will check that and try to give suitable answer. :)

Comment: I fixed the function and posted it as an answer to help out others.  thank you for giving me the needed hits to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

I encounter similar problem that force me to use this kind of operation. but the accepted answer giving me null value on all result. all i need to do was adding a `break` on the last `foreach` iteration.

> *just in-case i stumbled upon the same problem again, i will post this here*

The scenario that i have are like this:

[image: scenario]

When i'm using the accepted answer here, i got something like this:

```
//function to simulate the left join
function left_join_array($left, $right, $left_join_on, $right_join_on = NULL){
    $final= array();

    if(empty($right_join_on))
        $right_join_on = $left_join_on;

    foreach($left AS $k => $v){
        $final[$k] = $v;
        foreach($right AS $kk => $vv){
            if($v[$left_join_on] == $vv[$right_join_on]){
                foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                    $final[$k][$key] = $val; 
            } else {
                foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                    $final[$k][$key] = NULL;            
            }
        }
    }
   return $final;
}
```

[image: wrong_result]

That's not the result that i desired, because everything is `null` even though there's a matching data on the right table, and it was because the next iteration of `foreach` replacing the right value to `null`.

What i do is adding a `break` on the last `foreach`, also adding prefix on the appended value to avoid replacing the left table (just to be safe, in-case i have same name column between table)

```
//function to simulate the left join
function left_join_array($left, $right, $left_join_on, $right_join_on = NULL)
{
  $final = array();

  if (empty($right_join_on))
    $right_join_on = $left_join_on;

  foreach ($left as $k => $v) {
    $final[$k] = $v;
    foreach ($right as $kk => $vv) {
      if ($v[$left_join_on] == $vv[$right_join_on]) {
        foreach ($vv as $key => $val)
          $final[$k]['_' . $key] = $val; /* add prefix on the key */
        break; /* add break here */
      } else {
        foreach ($vv as $key => $val)
          $final[$k]['_' . $key] = NULL; /* add prefix on the key */
      }
    }
  }
  return $final;
}
```

[image: desiredresult]

and that's the desired result for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that your empty 'phone_call_id' and 'accout_id' values are null):

```
$joined_array = array();
foreach($right_array as $right_row){
    $phone_call_id = $right_row['phone_call_id'];
    $account_id    = $right_row['account_id'];
    foreach($left_array as $i => $left_row){
        if($left_row['phone_call_id'] === $phone_call_id){
            $left_row['account_id'] = $account_id;
            $joined_array[]         = $left_row;
        }
    }
}
//And here, we have to identify rows with empty 'phone_call_id'
foreach($left_array as $left_row){
    if($left_row['phone_call_id'] === null){
        $left_row['account_id'] = null;
        $joined_array[]         = $left_row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution,

worked for me use this,

```
function arrayLeftJoin($left,$right){
    foreach ($left as $lkey => $lvalue) {
        foreach ($right as $rkey => $rvalue) {
            if($lkey==$rkey){
                unset($left[$lkey]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $left;
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid this kind of operations. If you can, try to put all databases to same server and use SQL JOIN-s. PHP is not MYSQL. PHP is not dedicated for (left, right, etc) join tables. e.g. if you have huge numbers of records in left table returned by mysql and placed as result in array you can face big troubles with memory issue. Do MYSQL jobs using MYSQL, do PHP jobs using PHP. This way you will save: time, performances and neurons. :)

Comment: And what if you're working with a distributed system that have tables on different servers?

Comment: You might say that in that case you are in trouble. :(
In that case, you will have to use PHP to simulate JOIN ... However, you will very soon face the problems I have described earlier. Especially in LEFT JOIN cases over tables that contain very many rows (if you have such tables).
In some cases, you could meet problems that can not be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, old topic but we never know...can be useful.
Just a little update to Jaylen solution.

```
function left_join_array($left, $right, $left_join_on, $right_join_on = NULL){
     $final= array();

     if(empty($right_join_on))
         $right_join_on = $left_join_on;

     foreach($left AS $k => $v){
         $final[$k] = $v;
         foreach($right AS $kk => $vv){
             if($v[$left_join_on] === $vv[$right_join_on] ){
                 foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                     $final[$k][$key] = $val; 
             } else if(!isset($final[$k][$right_join_on])) {
                 foreach($vv AS $key => $val)
                     $final[$k][$key] = NULL;            
             }
         }
     }
    return $final;
 }
```