# Joining arrays in PHP (like MySQL join)

Tags: php, arrays, database, csv, left-join

I would like to join two arrays in PHP, the same as I could do with MySQL `join left`. I have two arrays:

- `$db_products` from database (it has `id` and `sku` fields)
- `$csv_prices` from a CSV file (it has `sku` and `price` fields)

`$db_products`: (it has 4000 items)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1012
            [sku] => asd123
    )
    [N] => Array
    (
            [id] => ...
            [sku] => ...
    )
)
```

`$csv_prices`: (it has 8000 items)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => asd123
            [price] => 15.50
    )
    [N] => Array
    (
            [sku] => ...
            [price] => ...
    )
)
```

The join is `$db_products[$key][sku] = $csv_prices[$key][sku]`. To find the matching pair, I am doing loops in loops which result in 4000 * 8000 check for match. It consumes a lot of energy and time, and I want to be more efficient.

I could lower by 10% the used time, by `unset()`-ing the used `$csv_prices[$key]`, but I want to be more efficient.

Comment: **you can look at this answer** [PHP ARRAY JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915944/join-multidimensional-array-like-sql/46951115#46951115)

Comment: In 2019 I have implemented a PHP library to do join, order, group by , etc to php arrays. Name of the library is arraybase. https://github.com/whizsid/arraybase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you loop through the `$csv_products` array once and set the SKU as the array key then you won't have to exponentially loop through that array each time you have a new product to find its match.

Instead, you just loop through the product array and use `isset()` to see if it exists or not.

This way you'll only need to do 1x `count($db_products)` and 1x `count($csv_prices)` repetitions, instead of `count($db_products) * count($csv_prices)` reps (12 thousand vs 32 million).

The concept could be considered to be similar to indexing in databases - you use the key you want to look up as the array key/index, meaning you don't have to loop through the array every time to find the record you want.

[Example:](https://eval.in/313061)

```
// Reindex the CSV array to use SKU as the key
$reindexed = array();
foreach ($csv_prices as $values) {
    $reindexed[$values['sku']] = $values;
}
unset($csv_prices);

// Join the prices
foreach ($db_products as &$product) {
    $sku = $product['sku'];
    $product['price'] = isset($reindexed[$sku]) ? $reindexed[$sku]['price'] : '';
}
```

Of course, you won't see a remarkable difference in performance until you start using large data sets - the change would be noticeable exponentially as the data sets grow.

Comment: Am totatally amused. It has the same result, but runs under 0.9 seconds instead of 17-18sec. Thank you, sir! :)

Comment: I was beginning to think I was the only one doing this as standard - lack of this knowledge is precisely why frameworks like Symfony don't scale well by default - but simple programming like this is precisely how it can be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

it's working fine for me

```
function left_join_arrays($key, $array1, $array2) {
    
    $i=0;
    foreach ($array1 as $arr1) {
        foreach ($array2 as $arr2) {
            if ($arr1[$key]==$arr2[$key]) {
                foreach(array_keys($arr2) as $key2){
                    if ($key != $key2) {
                        $array1[$i][$key2]=$arr2[$key2];
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $array1;
}
```